# Inheritance with two levels of generic abstract classes

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, android-asynctask, polymorphism

How is it that this code cannot launch the car's implementation of doInBackground. Am I missing something? I am not talking about an exception or a crash, it is just never executed.

Here is my code snippet :

FourWheels.java

```
public abstract class FourWheels<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
    @Override
    protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);
}
```

Car.java

```
public class Car extends FourWheels<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        String dummy = "dummy";
        return dummy;    
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
Car car = new Car();
FourWheels fourwheels = (FourWheels)car;
fourwheels.execute(); // This should call doInBackground from Car...
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `(FourWheels<Void, Void, String>)car;` ? If so it may be that it cannot infer the types to pass for the task.

Comment: Show us the `execute()` implementation, please.

Comment: How do you verify that it is not called?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I just tried and it didn't work.
ericBn : Execute is part of AsyncTask, I didn't modify it.
Sotirios : I just put a breakpoint in it. It is never called.

Comment: To clarify when you use AsyncTask, you call execute and after some logic it will automatically doInBackground

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: I just checked and no exception are thrown. (I tried with ClassCastException and Exception)

Comment: Try defining the `protected void onPostExecute(Result result)` method in your Child class and see if it calls that with the result.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I just tried and it is not being called either. Which is normal since doInBackground isn't called either.

Comment: Just was checking to make sure for some reason it wasn't just spawning a thread and leaving it alone and not hitting the breakpoint.  Does it work if you call the car.execute() directly?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond Yes it does!